# i can read 1 bunch of numbers from a text document but not another

Tags: python, string

TLDR: for some reason my script is able to work with one list of numbers but not another. i think the problem is obviously how different the numbers are but I'm not sure how to fix.

my script has a function which opens a file (we'll call a) reads the fist line, reads the rest (which it calls arest) then reads another file (file b) and gets b rest.

it works very well on these files

AAA.txt

```
test a  line 1
3,6,8,99,-4,0.6,8
0,9,7,5,7,9,5
2,2,2,2,2,2,5
7,5,1,2,12,8,0.9
```

bbb.txt

```
test b  line 1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
55,0,90,09,1,2,3,
8,9,7,6,8,7,6
3,43,5,8,2,4,1
```

below is my script

```
def mi_func(P):
    f=open(P, 'r')
    first = f.readline()
    restlines= f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return first, restlines


afirst,arest = mi_func('aaa.txt')
bfirst,brest = mi_func('bbb.txt')


arest = [x.lstrip('0').split(',') for x in arest if x != '\n']
brest = [x.lstrip('0').split(',') for x in brest if x != '\n']

for i in range(len(arest)):
    arest[i] = [float(x) for x in arest[i] if x != '\n' and x!= '']

print(arest)
for i in range(len(brest)):
    s= brest[i] = [float(x) for x in brest[i] if x != '\n' and x != '']

c = arest[:]
for i in range(len(arest)):
    for j in range(len(arest[i])):
        c[i][j] = (arest[i][j]**2)+(brest[i][j]**2)
print(c)


d=arest[:]
import math
for i in range(len(c)):
    for j in range(len(c[i])):
        d[i][j] = math.sqrt(c[i][j])
print('hello')
print(d)                                                    

[[3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 99.0, -4.0, 0.6, 8.0], [9.0, 7.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 5.0] [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0], [7.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 12.0, 8.0, 0.9]]
[[10.0, 40.0, 73.0, 9817.0, 41.0, 36.36, 113.0], [3106.0, 49.0, 8125.0, 130.0, 82.0, 29.0], [68.0, 85.0, 53.0, 40.0, 68.0, 53.0, 61.0], [58.0, 1874.0, 26.0, 68.0, 148.0, 80.0, 1.81]]
hello
[[3.1622776601683795, 6.324555320336759, 8.54400374531753, 99.08077512817509, 6.4031242374328485, 6.029925372672534, 10.63014581273465], [55.731499172371095, 7.0, 90.13878188659973, 11.40175425099138, 9.055385138137417, 5.385164807134504], [8.246211251235321, 9.219544457292887, 7.280109889280518, 6.324555320336759, 8.246211251235321, 7.280109889280518, 7.810249675906654], [7.615773105863909, 43.289721643826724, 5.0990195135927845, 8.246211251235321, 12.165525060596439, 8.94427190999916, 1.3453624047073711]]
```

this makes me very happy. 
however i become sad when i try a different file ccc.txt or ddd.txt because it doesn't work. 
ccc.txt

```
first line :)
3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08 6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08 1.6410391288046437544e-08 6.4151550079023113112e-08 9.9077814220256712144e-08 4.8228459783414887112e-08 1.6503915571969716123e-08 5.0759765831642425139e-08 1.4163943549368568877e-08 0.9171874262950143401e-08
```

and ddd.txt
first line :}

```
7.9190559956084232425e-08 4.0014656026579413249e-08 7.9587577896814211040e-08 7.8662419833581675357e-08 0.4063733044143882268e-08 9.5732330998844513040e-08 8.6618234806655863631e-08 2.0072870251849178430e-08 6.7864248806722254548e-08 1.2134776106517812316e-08
4.7565190913441753115e-08 5.1557086343029653458e-08 6.3693801211606923532e-08 7.8897108738118126312e-08 9.4510334836961360301e-08 7.4880836459074272283e-08 4.9268327788150989424e-08 1.8466453757372403026e-08 6.2011855819003971679e-08 2.0783930984602632852e-08
```

heres me running it with ccc.txt and ddd.txt

```
def mi_func(P):
    f=open(P, 'r')
    first = f.readline()
    restlines= f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return first, restlines


afirst,arest = mi_func('ccc.txt')
bfirst,brest = mi_func('ddd.txt')


arest = [x.lstrip('0').split(',') for x in arest if x != '\n']
brest = [x.lstrip('0').split(',') for x in brest if x != '\n']

for i in range(len(arest)):
    arest[i] = [float(x) for x in arest[i] if x != '\n' and x!= '']

print(arest)
for i in range(len(brest)):
    s= brest[i] = [float(x) for x in brest[i] if x != '\n' and x != '']

c = arest[:]
for i in range(len(arest)):
    for j in range(len(arest[i])):
        c[i][j] = (arest[i][j]**2)+(brest[i][j]**2)
print(c)


d=arest[:]
import math
for i in range(len(c)):
    for j in range(len(c[i])):
        d[i][j] = math.sqrt(c[i][j])
print('hello')
print(d)                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b37cafd33482> in <module>()
     15 
     16 for i in range(len(arest)):
---> 17     arest[i] = [float(x) for x in arest[i] if x != '\n' and x!= '']
     18 
     19 print(arest)

<ipython-input-8-b37cafd33482> in <listcomp>(.0)
     15 
     16 for i in range(len(arest)):
---> 17     arest[i] = [float(x) for x in arest[i] if x != '\n' and x!= '']
     18 
     19 print(arest)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08 6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08\n'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, is it the size of the numbers causing problems or lack of commas or what?

i want it to work work these files too

Comment: You split your lines on commas, and the numbers in the second set of examples are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The files you gave seem to have two different delimiters, a space or a comma. You could use `re.split` to split on either of those and then turn the values to floats.

```
In[2]: aaa = """\
  ...: 3,6,8,99,-4,0.6,8
  ...: 0,9,7,5,7,9,5
  ...: 2,2,2,2,2,2,5
  ...: 7,5,1,2,12,8,0.9"""
  ...: 
  ...: bbb = """\
  ...: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  ...: 55,0,90,09,1,2,3
  ...: 8,9,7,6,8,7,6
  ...: 3,43,5,8,2,4,1"""
  ...: 
  ...: ccc = """\
  ...: 3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08 6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
  ...: 0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08 1.6410391288046437544e-08 6.4151550079023113112e-08 9.9077814220256712144e-08 4.8228459783414887112e-08 1.6503915571969716123e-08 5.0759765831642425139e-08 1.4163943549368568877e-08 0.9171874262950143401e-08"""
  ...: 
  ...: ddd = """\
  ...: 7.9190559956084232425e-08 4.0014656026579413249e-08 7.9587577896814211040e-08 7.8662419833581675357e-08 0.4063733044143882268e-08 9.5732330998844513040e-08 8.6618234806655863631e-08 2.0072870251849178430e-08 6.7864248806722254548e-08 1.2134776106517812316e-08
  ...: 4.7565190913441753115e-08 5.1557086343029653458e-08 6.3693801211606923532e-08 7.8897108738118126312e-08 9.4510334836961360301e-08 7.4880836459074272283e-08 4.9268327788150989424e-08 1.8466453757372403026e-08 6.2011855819003971679e-08 2.0783930984602632852e-08"""
In[3]: import re
  ...: 
  ...: for file in (aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd):
  ...:     for line in file.splitlines():
  ...:         print([float(num) for num in re.split(r'[, ]', line)])
  ...:     print()
  ...: 
[3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 99.0, -4.0, 0.6, 8.0]
[0.0, 9.0, 7.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 5.0]
[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0]
[7.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 12.0, 8.0, 0.9]

[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
[55.0, 0.0, 90.0, 9.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[8.0, 9.0, 7.0, 6.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0]
[3.0, 43.0, 5.0, 8.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0]

[3.194834345278755e-08, 8.271317079043527e-08, 9.299740746607279e-08, 2.2201974063356576e-08, 4.7184351703512535e-08, 6.486923700643942e-08, 5.610565700609329e-08, 2.5869788723656168e-08, 3.2336150408719795e-08, 1.3711755095387755e-08]
[8.466139114156927e-09, 8.65522654891257e-08, 1.6410391288046436e-08, 6.415155007902312e-08, 9.907781422025671e-08, 4.822845978341489e-08, 1.6503915571969717e-08, 5.0759765831642425e-08, 1.4163943549368568e-08, 9.171874262950143e-09]

[7.919055995608423e-08, 4.001465602657941e-08, 7.958757789681421e-08, 7.866241983358167e-08, 4.063733044143882e-09, 9.573233099884451e-08, 8.661823480665587e-08, 2.007287025184918e-08, 6.786424880672226e-08, 1.2134776106517812e-08]
[4.756519091344175e-08, 5.1557086343029653e-08, 6.369380121160693e-08, 7.889710873811813e-08, 9.451033483696137e-08, 7.488083645907428e-08, 4.926832778815099e-08, 1.8466453757372402e-08, 6.201185581900397e-08, 2.0783930984602632e-08]
```